# If-else One line statement (with string and integer)

Tags: java, if-statement, static

I'm creating a program. This code below is the Java program. Checking if the value of B and H, input by the user is equal to zero. If it is true, then a math formula will execute which is `p =  b*h` then if it is false, a string will be shown on the console. But the thing is, it keeps on giving me an error that string cannot be converted to int or int cannot be converted to string.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StaticProject{
    
    static {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int B = input.nextInt();
        int H = input.nextInt();
        int P;
        
        
        int solution = B>=0 && H>=0 ?  P = B*H : "java.lang.Exception: Breadth and height must be positive";
    }
```

How can I improve my coding when it comes in doing this oneline bi-conditionals statement? Any tips?

Comment: That's what if/else statements are for. The ternary operator is only useful if both the true and the false-side expressions have the same type and meaning, which is not the case for you.

Comment: This is a shortened conditional *assignment* statement. Whatever is in the else clause will be evaluated and then assigned to `solution`.

Comment: your solution Type is `int`, and your else statement returns an `String`, this is the cause of error.

Comment: *"How can I improve my coding when it comes in doing this oneline bi-conditionals statement?"* - by not using it and instead writing proper if-else statements that are more readable anyway.

Comment: The conditional operator `?:` is used to express a value that depends on a condition. It is not a replacement for the if-statement.

Answer (score 2):

your solution variable Type is `int`, and your else statement returns an `String`, this is the cause of error.

you can change your code to this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int B = input.nextInt();
    int H = input.nextInt();
    int P;

    if (B >= 0 && H >= 0) {
        P = B*H;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Breadth and height must be positive");
    }

    System.out.println(P);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign string to an int variable, if your statement is evaluated as false.
You need to use if/else condition, which both sides have the same type.
In your case, it's not possible.
another possibility is use System.out.println() command, to print the result of whatever resulted by the condition.

Answer (score 0):

There is no virtue in writing code in as few lines as possible. By all means, don't write *unnecessary* code, but just don't think that concise code is objectively "better".

The best type of code to write is simple code. Maybe it's a little more verbose; but if you write code that people can understand at a glance, they know what it does straight away.

Here is how I would write it:

```
if (B < 0 || H < 0) {
  // Actually, non-negative, rather than positive.
  throw new Exception("Breadth and height must be positive");

  // Or, maybe, don't even use exceptions at all:
  // System.out.println("The message");
  // return;
}

// No need for `solution` variable.
P = B * H;
System.out.println(P);
```

Of course, you might argue this isn't code *everybody* will understand at a glance. Sure. Readability is subjective; but I assert that anybody with just a little bit of experience in Java can work it out.

---

You *can* write a conditional `?:` expression which results in an exception being thrown in the case of the condition being false.

```
// Define a method which does the throwing.
static int justThrow(String message) throws Exception {
  throw new Exception(message);
}

// In the main method:
int solution = B>=0 && H>=0 ?  P = B*H : justThrow("Breadth and height must be positive");
```

I emphasize that you *can*, but you **shouldn't** do this. It's obscure. It's trying to be "a bit too clever". It will have people reading your code and scratching their heads, because they will wonder why you wrote a method for something so simple; what is the `solution` variable for, given that it will have the same value as `P` etc.